# Can't get IP from Router using a switch (TZ 170)

Tags: networking, router

The setup is the following:

The modem is connected to the router (Sonicwall TZ-170). All computers connected to the router directly have no problem accessing the internet. To the router used to be a hub connected. The hub recently died and got replaced by a switch. Using the hub, all the computers connected to the hub, could get an ip from the router and had no problem connecting. Now with the switch however the computers can't connect anymore.

Do I have to change a setting within the router? Do I need to setup the switch somehow?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What model switch is it?

Comment: Netgear FS 105.

Comment: How much IP the router will provide? Did you set it before?

Comment: I have never manually set an IP. According to the router it should be able to handle 20 devices connected to it. So far there are only 2 connected directly which both work. Everything connected to the switch doesnt work.

Comment: did you try; power down everything. disconnect. add all devices directly to the switch, then switch to router. Power up from router, switch, computers, 2 minutes between each power up. Also check your switch to router cable, try another.

Comment: Did you accidentally connect the switch to the router's WAN port or zone port? Are you 100% sure the switch is connected to the same router port the hub was connected to?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Netgear FS 105 is a simple non-managed switch, you dont need to configure anything to use it with your router. It looks like the switch is not connected to the router correctly. Check following things:

- Is the LED on the switch lightning correctly?
- The switch is specified to have auto-sensing for crossover cable. Nevertheless try to use another ethernet cable between the router and the switch. Try a crossover cable if available.
- Try to use other port, both on router and on switch, to avoid a phyical defect port.
- As last ressort, try using another switch if available.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot the TZ-170.  Chances are the switch ports MAC address table is holding old data (due to the previous hub) and now those MAC routes are invalid.